# Permission Denied for linux-x86/bin/acp while compiling android source

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu-12.04, android-source, android-make

I am compiling android source code. The commands were

```
   aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
   export OUT_DIR_COMMON_BASE=/media/entertainment/out
   make -j4 otapackage
```

during the build process, after some time an error occurs:

```
     target Symbolic: libz (/media/entertainment/out/androidworkingDIR/target/product/hammerhead/symbols/system/lib/libz.so)

    /bin/bash: /media/entertainment/out/androidworkingDIR/host/linux-x86/bin/acp: Permission denied

    make: *** [/media/entertainment/out/androidworkingDIR/target/product/hammerhead/symbols/system/lib/libz.so] Error 126

    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

    target StaticLib: libc (/media/entertainment/out/androidworkingDIR/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/libc.a)
```

**For your information:**

I have my normal user access(Read/write) in /media/entertainment/

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Can anybody please help me out of this?

Comment: Is /media/entertainment mounted with the noexec option? What file system is it?

Comment: No the media is not mounted with noexec option.

Comment: Okay. I suspect that NTFS isn't supported for builds, or you need to mount it in some other way. The build simply needs to be able to run executables from the source directory.

Comment: Yeah buddy perhaps you are right. I checked all the files in that NTFS partition, they lacked 'x' permission. Moreover, chmod wasnt changing permissions of any of those files.

Comment: So, now I am trying to build on an ext4 partition. Lets see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was with NTFS partition i.e. the out directory for the build process should not be in a NTFS partition.

I created a new ext-4 partition, and everything went smooth.